# Setting up multiple web servers - Cloud

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, cloud-hosting, rackspace

Our site traffic has grown large enough that we need to implement two web servers.

We've signed up for the RackSpace cloud and we're wanting to move our eCommerce platform accross. We're running Magento.

Basically I have a few issues.

I'm in the testing phase at the moment and I've built two web servers which connect to a dedicated DB server and am using the Cloud Load Balancer that Rackspace provide, however I'm not sure on a couple of things.

1) having two web servers, I seem to lose my session frequently. How do you get around this? I don't have a SAN. Should I use our dedicated DB server and NFS mount a drive to have a shared sessions directory?

2) Where should we host our media, such as product images etc? At the moment, they're on each individual server and I have been using Rsync to sync the directories. I have toyed with the idea of using the Rackspace CDN but if the admin staff add a product, how should the image be pushed to the cloud? Should it be done using API commands at the time of image upload or is there a good way I can do it at OS level?

3) Any other advice about this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question about session persistence, there's a few ways to get around losing your persistence. Storing your sessions in a database, memcache or shared storage is one way, which may work fine, but may introduce a single point-of-failure into your environment.

Another way may be to see if you can have your loadbalancer perform session persistence, by forcing connections from a user to a single server (hopefully using [cookies](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/cookie)). I'm not sure if this is an option with Rackspace Cloud loadbalancers.

Comment: You can get around the SPoF on memcached instances with the Repcached patch. http://repcached.lab.klab.org/